# Iphone style on button not overwriting

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

i have some styling on the more button http://www.mw-app.cp.thedms.co.uk/thedms.aspx?dms=106 ( http://bit.ly/ArzcYi for faster typing) here, on all browsers and phones it looks how i want.

However on the iPhone its still seems to be pulling default styles (which are internalally set up styles) through and looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wefr.jpg and for the life of my i cant figure out why it is overwriting. Hope someone can shed some light on it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is for CSS and a mobile site not an app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need this is your CSS for the button.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Think vitamin has a great article on this topic. Cheers

http://thinkvitamin.com/design/styling-submit-buttons-for-mobile-safari/

Comment: The link is no longer valid